# How to timeout a Bash command and count the number of lines emitted to stdout?

Tags: bash

I'd like to do something like `timeout 12s tail -f access.log | wc -l` but I'm not seeing the output from `wc`. What needs to be done to be able to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `--foreground` option with `timeout`:

```
timeout --foreground 12s tail -f access.log | wc -l
```

As per `man timeout`:

```
--foreground   when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,
               allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals;
               in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
```

Comment: Be sure to wait long enough when initially trying this out. For example, I had first started using `timeout --foreground 1s` but the command took much longer than 1 second to return presumably because of the large volume that needed to be processed.